# After installing to the GAC remove original file

Tags: .net, gac

After installing an assembly into the GAC using 'gacutil /i {0}' can I remove the orignal assembly, ie the assembly at path '{0}'?

Comment: Uninstalling requires the assembly display name, not the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually you dont need to......in the assembly settings youhave to remove the "copy to local" property. Once you compile the code the local copy of assembly in the project debug folder will be removed.But if you have a assembly from a anonymous location then u can delete the assembly after installing in th GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the original assembly but you may need to put the assembly in the same path if you want to uninstall later.

Comment: Sounds implausible. A reasonable uninstall api would work with the strong name of the assembly. Do you have a source for this?